# Sending only updated attributes while save in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, request

Here is the code:

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            name: "name",
            surname: "surname"
        },
        url: "/cgi-bin/test.pl",
        urlRoot: "/cgi-bin/test.pl"
    });

var person = null; 

$(document).ready(function(){
        person = new Person();
        person.set("name", "Alex");
        person.save({'name':'Jonh'}, {patch: true});
});
```

When I do the

```
person.save({'name':'Jonh'}, {patch: true});
```

I see the POST request to server with payload:

> {"name":"Jonh","surname":"surname"}

But why does the surname attribute is also passed? I don't want to send it. 
I want to send only the name attribute. How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`surname` is sent to the server because is one of the `defaults` [attributes](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-defaults) of the model. When the model is initialized Backbone prepopulates the attributes of the model with this object. If you want to skip this attributes when saving to the server you will have to create an object with the attributes of the model without the defaults values and pass it to the `save` method:

```
var values = {};
_.each(person.attributes, function(value, key){  
       if (person.defaults[key] !== value){
          values[key]=value;
       }
});
person.save(null, {attrs: values, patch: true});
```

Also you can remove the object `defaults` from the declaration of your model, it´s not mandatory.